# Could not find or load main class when trying loading to heroku

Tags: java, heroku

I'm trying to load my java app on to heroku, the Bild succeeded, but heroku seems not to be able to load my main class, is there anything wrong with my profile?
`worker: java -jar Testbot/org.javacord:javacord:3.1.2.jar`
Or the structure of my project is wrong [project structure and heroku erro code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5wY0.png)

Comment: What does `jar -tvf <your jar file>` say?

Comment: do you have a main class? how does your manifest file look like? have you added java correctly to your environment variables classpath?

Comment: Where do I excute jar -tvf <your jar file>?

Comment: I have a main class, it's in src.main.java.com.github.Dingmoc. The main class runs on it's own when I run it.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong building method. One must use gradel on this one